# How to Call the method Confirm

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a `JS` Method as follows: ( I don't know if it's 100% correct)

```
<script Type="Text/Javascript">

if (confirm("Are you SUre ?")) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}

</script>
```

And have some doubts:

First: I have a folder called `JS`  and i'm planing to put it there, is this correct?

Second: I will use this on an `Edit` page, so when the customer `click`on the button `edit` I'd like this confirmation with some message like `"Are you Sure?` and the buttons Yes/No
If the customer `clicks` on the `Yes` then i'll keep with my `edit on database`.
So how do I do that ? How I call this method at the moment that the customer click on the `ImageButton` ?

One more thing: How Do I get the return of this method and work with it on my aspx.cs using C#?

I tried the code below, but didn't work =\ it shows me the popUp but even when I click `cancel` it goes to the `OnClick` Method

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Btn_Alterar" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Imgs/btAlterar.jpg" OnClick="Btn_Alterar_Click" OnClientClick="confirm()" />
```

Comment: Guys, if you're going to vote down, you need to leave a comment. His question is well formed and valid.

Comment: You stopped here just to give me a DOwnVote and say this ? 
What wrong have I done ?

Comment: The `language` attribute has been deprecated long ago. Use `type="text/javascript"` instead. And you even don't need those HTML comment tokens anymore.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel So I remove the language and replace it with Type="Text/javascript" ?

Comment: Indeed, and you can remove those `<!--` and `-->`.

Comment: Well look at the 5 people that up voted in retaliation to the downvotes. I think he did well out of it :)

Comment: if you are ok with adding the AjaxControltoolkit, then you can consider using the confirmationButton: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_ConfirmButton.ashx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. It will pop up the question and if they say yes then will process the server side code (as an example).

JS:

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
function doConfirm() {
    if (confirm("Are you SUre ?")) {
      //Person has said Yes, do your thing. Next line will allow the server side code to be processed
      return true
    } else {
      //User said No, do nothing and leave next line so the function call exits. 
      return false
    }
}
-->
</script>
```

ASP.NET Control:

```
<asp:ImageButton id="bMyButton" runat="server" onClientClick="doConfirm()" OnClick="DoServerSideCode" />
```

.CS

```
protected void DoServerSideCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This will be called if JS is disabled OR the user clicks Yes. If the user clicks No then this won't be called. You can do DB logix here.
}
```

**Edit:** (with thanks to @justnS)

Another implementation would be:

ASP.NET Control:

```
<asp:ImageButton id="bMyButton" runat="server" onClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" OnClick="DoServerSideCode" />
```

The above is exactly the same as the previous implementation but takes less code and is done inline.

Comment: Sure, but Where do I call the method doCOnfirm() ? Thanks

Comment: See the ASP.NET Control part. It will call when you click the ImageButton.

Comment: Got ya ! Thanks ! But tell me, how i'll make an if/else according to the return true/false ? Sorry I used to programm on WebForms ;s dont know much of web yet.

Comment: I just added some comments to the JS section. It should explain.

Comment: Thanks webnoob, just one more thing. Cant I recieve the return true/false on my aspx.cs and work with the answer using C# ? Because I need to make and Edit on DataBase and I need the answer of the customer... Really thanks @webnoob !

Comment: `return confirm('Are you sure?')`

Comment: @justnS - Always miss the obvious simple choice :)

Comment: Sorry take so long to answer I was at my lunch time hehe... Thanks webnoob and justinS for helping me out =) Really appreciate that !
On the DoServerSideCode how will I say if(false){} else {} ?as I have no method to put on the IF( ----- ) ? Because I already have the OnClick() done... Just want to know how to recieve the return that will be (False or True)

Comment: It won't get there if it's false so you don't need to.

Comment: @webnoob IF the return is `false` I'll not execute my query, if it's true, then I'll update my table, you get it ? I need to know if the customer want to update the table or not ;s How could I do that. I edited my post see please, nothing happens =\ The Confirm didnt fire.

Comment: I understand your requirement but you are not reading what I have said properly. `DoServerSideCode` will ONLY be run if the user hits YES. You need to post all the code you are using in your edit as it's not enough.

Comment: WOOOORKED *------* Thanks a bunch @webnoob ! I really don't know how to thanks all your patiance ! and Thanks for you too justnS =)
Now It's working just like I wanted *---* GodBlessYou !! (hope my english is correct!). Last Thing: With this `return confirm(text)` I cant throw away my confirm.js right ?

Comment: If you are using `onClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"` then you don't need confirm.js, correct. No problem for the help :)

Comment: @webnoob tell me just one more thing hehe, what if I want to pop up a message with Yes/No just like confirm(); But now , I have an `IF` if true then shows up the pop up confirm(). Is there a way to do that ? 
And Thanks again !

Comment: Yes, you could use my original example with the confirm function and add an if statement around the `if (confirm("Are you SUre ?")) {` section.

Answer (score 0):

$('#mylink').click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();
//Have the action to delete something in DB? go to it here..

}

Of course, you need jQuery..